# MS Ribbon: how to create button icon dynamically (c++)?

Tags: c++, button, icons, ribbon

I want to create the same dynamic gallery as in MS Word numeric/bullet list settings: when client chooses new symbol for list - new button with this symbol is added into gallery.
**Problem is that ribbon does not want display images that are not in resources.**
Is any possible way to do this in c++?

Comment: A [quick search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ribbon%20iuiimage%20example) turns up lots of results on [how to do this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/228821/Ribbon-with-Cplusplus-Part-Using-Galleries-with)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I see just about "how to load from resource file". I need create bitmap in code, not load from res file. But if I create it - ribbon doesn't want to display this image.

Comment: Actually, the second link I posted does show you how to do it. In the function `CBorderStyleHandler::CreateUIImageFromBitmapResource`  they load a resource in a `HBITMAP`, which is then used to create the ribbon item. However, there are lots of ways to draw to a `HBITMAP` in memory, via the GDI APIs. And there are many libraries that will load an image file from disk into a `HBITMAP`.